# Selecting the Fields from the View in Oracle database according to the date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am really new to Oracle database and queries. I have a requirement where I have to query the view in the Oracle database in a BizTalk application,and the View is like this

```
EmpNumber |  Name  | TermDate
------------------------------
E001      |  ABC   | (null)
E002      |  DEF   | 13-DEC-14
E003      |  GHI   | (null)
E004      |  JKL   | 11-NOV-14
E005      |  MNO   | (null)
E005      |  PQR   | 10-DEC-14
```

What my query should do is, it should select the Records with the TermDate null and TermDate 7 days ago from today. So here is how I want the selected records to be

```
EmpNumber |  Name  | TermDate
------------------------------
E001      |  ABC   | (null)
E002      |  DEF   | 13-DEC-14
E003      |  GHI   | (null)
E005      |  MNO   | (null)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think Stack Overflow is over-enthusiastically recommending MySQL as a tag.  I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `sysdate` gets you the current date/time.  So you want:

```
select *
from view v
where TermDate is null or TermDate >= trunc(sysdate) - 7;
```

Comment: Select * can be a risky thing to do code wise, it would be better to select the fields explicitly.